# CoreData - fetch code swift3

Tags: swift3, nsfetchrequest

below is not working throwing an error , please help how to write a code for fetching data from Users entity.

attached screen[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2Ngi.png)

Comment: What is the error? Also post your code in question as text, not in picture.

Comment: Did it helped you?

Answer (score 1):

Grabbing `appDelegate` object and `context`

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
```

Adding a record in Core Data

```
let user = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "UsersClass", into: context) as! UsersClass
user.userName = "Rajan"
appDelegate.saveContext()
```

Fetching

```
let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<UsersClass> = UsersClass.fetchRequest()
```

And then execute this request

```
do {
    let searchResults = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    for trans in searchResults {
        print(trans.username!)
    }
}
catch {
    //Handle error
}
```

**UsersClass+CoreDataProperties.swift**

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension UsersClass {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<UsersClass> {
        return NSFetchRequest<UsersClass>(entityName: "UsersClass");
    }

    @NSManaged public var userName: String?

}
```

Here is the [Sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d8tspjgh83snrpd/CoreDataSample.zip?dl=0) which I made.

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'executeFetchRequest:error: <null> is not a valid NSFetchRequest.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001105e534b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010d51121e objc_exception_throw + 48
 2   CoreData                            0x000000010d9d4f6c -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 4972
 3   libswiftCoreData.dylib              0x000000010fb37e78

Comment: At least add some record into it then it will fetch . Also show your managed object class i.e.  Usersclass

Comment: can you please share code for creating and fetching data....i am new to swift iOS

Comment: @Srini Did it helped you

Comment: Well it helped me a treat. I don't know how many issues you had in your code but you at least needed to change NSFetchRequestResult with the name of your custom class